# Update column based on aggregate function with sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to have a column with data taken from a count() function with a subquery. I am working with a temporary table at the moment and it is created by:

```
CREATE TABLE tempfact1 AS
  (
    SELECT coursesloc.courseID, preferences.appid, campuses.campusid
    FROM coursesloc, preferences, campuses
  WHERE coursesloc.courseID = preferences.courseID AND coursesloc.campusid = campuses.campusid AND preferences.prefaccepted = 'Y'
  )
;

ALTER TABLE tempfact1
ADD TNA NUMERIC;
```

Then I run the following to try and generate the TNA (total number of applicants per campus) with the following:

```
UPDATE tempfact1
SET TNA = (SELECT COUNT(appid) FROM tempfact1 GROUP BY campusid)
```

Which I cannot do because it is returning more than one row. I'm unsure how to get it to only output one row at a time in the UPDATE, or if there is an easier and better way to just do this in the CREATE TABLE command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created one small demo for your question...

```
/*Demo table....*/
create table mtp (rno integer,name varchar(max))

/*Demo Data....*/
insert into mtp values (1,'a')
insert into mtp values (1,'b')
insert into mtp values (2,'c')
insert into mtp values (2,'d')
insert into mtp values (2,'e')

/* Select Result, use this countid column for your new table...*/
select 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rno)as countid
    ,rno
    ,name
From mtp
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about OVER (PARITION BY column), which was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try by removing the `GROUP BY` clause. It will return multiple rows , i.e. count for each campus_id.

Comment: actually he wants like this, and if you want to append group by then this question is wrong..

Comment: That doesn't work, it only sets every row in the TNA column to be the total count of the tempfact1 table which is not what I want. I specifically need the counts of appid by each campus.

Comment: In case group by is needed, then maybe you can try by mapping the campus_id, to avoid multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Create the table as:

```
 CREATE TABLE tempfact1 AS
      ( SELECT courseID,appid,campusid,COUNT(*) TNA 
        FROM(
        SELECT coursesloc.courseID, preferences.appid, campuses.campusid
        FROM coursesloc, preferences, campuses
         WHERE coursesloc.courseID = preferences.courseID AND coursesloc.campusi=campuses.campusid AND preferences.prefaccepted = 'Y' ) GROUP BY campusid
    );
```

Please correct if there are any syntax errors